Convert a CLOB to data table -- Oracle
I'm trying to convert an xml (stored into a CLOB) into a table...
I will love to go from:
<formula>
    <name>
        <string>First</string>
        <string>Second</string>
        <string>Third</string>
        <string>Forth</string>
    </name>
    <equation>
        <string>a+1=b</string>
        <string>b*2=c</string>
        <string>c+5=d</string>
        <string>priority(a,b,c)</string>    
    </equation>
</formula>

to:
enter image description here
(it's not how i will have created the xml... but it's the format that i have to work with.)
After a lot of googling, i'm able to extract the first record with the code below, but i will like to have a dynamic list (the number of records in the xml file vary)
SELECT d.profile_name, xtab.Equation
FROM (
        select distinct profile_name,
                XMLTYPE(up.my_clob) as xml
        from mytable  
        where profile_name like 'A'
        ) d, 
xmltable('/' 
        PASSING d.xml 
        COLUMNS Equation varchar2(200) path '//equation/string[1]/text()'
        )xtab;


Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551 and for tables https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables

with data(xml) as (
    select xmltype(q'~<formula>
    <name>
        <string>First</string>
        <string>Second</string>
        <string>Third</string>
        <string>Forth</string>
    </name>
    <equation>
        <string>a+1=b</string>
        <string>b*2=c</string>
        <string>c+5=d</string>
        <string>priority(a,b,c)</string>    
    </equation>
</formula>~')
    from dual
)
select ntab.name, etab.equation 
from data d,
    xmltable(
        '/formula/name/string' 
        PASSING d.xml
        COLUMNS 
        nord for ordinality,
        name varchar2(2000) path '.'
    ) ntab,
    xmltable(
        '/formula/equation/string' 
        PASSING d.xml
        COLUMNS 
        eord for ordinality,
        Equation varchar2(2000) path '.'
    ) etab
where nord = eord
;


And possible to do it with only 1 XMLTABLE:
select
    name, equation
from data d,
    xmltable(
        'for $i at $idx in /formula/equation/string/text()
        return <pair><name>{/formula/name/string[$idx]}</name>
            <equation>{$i}</equation></pair>' 
        PASSING d.xml
        columns 
            name varchar2(4000) path './name',
            equation varchar2(4000) path './equation'
    ) t
;


Wow, thanks everyone for your help!!

@Ben, it is a good idea to mark working solution as Answer
